# How do I get the distance and ID of the closest point in one spatial dataframe to each point in another spatial dataframe

Tags: r, r-sp

I have two data frames, set1 and set2 both with lat long coordinates. I want to

1) find the closest point in set2 to each point in set1
2) record the distance and add it to a column in set1
3) get the id and add it to a column in set1

I have written the following code, but it is very slow for my full data set (50,000 points in set1 and 1000 in set2).

This code works but it is slow. Perhaps I can convert it to an apply statement? The problem is that I do not know how.

Thank you

```
## load in library
library(spdep)
library(sp)
library(geosphere)

## create some fake data and convert them to spatial objects
set1<- data.frame(cbind(runif(25000,-10.8544921875,2.021484375),runif(40,49.82380908513249,59.478568831926395)))
names(set1)<-c("lon","lat")
coordinates(set1)<-~lon+lat


set2<-data.frame(cbind(runif(1000,-10.8544921875,2.021484375),runif(40,49.82380908513249,59.478568831926395)))
names(set2)<-c("lon","lat")
coordinates(set2)<-~lon+lat
set2$ID<-seq(1:dim(data.frame(set2))[1])

plot(set1, col="blue", pch=16)
plot(set2, col="grey", pch=16, add=TRUE)

##Calculate distances from points in set1 to points in set2
dists.set1.set2<-distm (set1, set2,fun = distHaversine)/1609

## create a variable for the distance from every point in set1 to the nearest point in set2
set1$distance.to.nearest.point<-apply(dists.set1.set2,1,min)


## Get the id of the point in set2 closest to each point in set1    
for (i in 1:dim(set1)[1]){          


 if(length(which(dists.set1.set2[i,]==set1$distance.to.nearest.point[i]))>0){           
set1$closest.point.in.set2[i]<-set2$ID[which(dists.set1.set2[i,]==set1$distance.to.nearest.point[i])]           
  }         
}
```

Comment: From which package does the `distm()` function come from?

Comment: comes from the geosphere package

Answer (score 1):

let me know if the following meets your needs.

In the example you provide, `dists.set1.set2` is a distance matrix of 25,000 rows (for `set1`) and 1,000 columns (`set2`). To obtain the ID's of the *nearest* points in `set2` to `set1` you will order the distances of each row, and take the first column, using the `order()` function. This represents the **index** of the row in `set2` that correspond to the shortest distance between `set2`and a particular point in `set1`.

The following is the code to carry that out, and perform a few logical tests to see that we are indeed taking the point from `set2` that is closest to `set1`.

Example:

```
# Obtain ORDER of position of set1 in increasing distance -- note that R transposed the matrix, hence the need for `t`
dist_order = dists.set1.set2 %>% apply(MARGIN = 1, FUN = order) %>% t

# Verify that the order is increasing. Top row is the closest distance.
dist_sorted = dists.set1.set2 %>% apply(MARGIN = 1, FUN = sort) %>% t

index_shortest_dist = dist_order[,1]

# Make set1 spdf and add data frame columns for the closest set2 ID and the closest distance.
set1 = sp::SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = set1, data = data.frame(ClosestID = rep(NA, NROW(set1)),
                                                                   ClosestDist = rep(NA, NROW(set1))))

# Pull the proper data from set2. Use pull to obtain a vector instead of a df.
set1@data$ClosestID = set2 %>% data.frame %>% slice(index_shortest_dist) %>% pull(ID)

# Pull the proper data from the sorted distance list.
set1@data$ClosestDist = dist_sorted[,1]

# Verify a few test cases

# Random row position
rand = sample(seq(1, NROW(set1)), size = 1)

# Take the ID generated previously from from corresponding row in set1
closest_ID = set1[rand,]$ClosestID

# Take the corresponding point from set2 using the ID obtained from the previous operation
set2_closest_candidate = set2[which(closest_ID == set2$ID),]

# What's the difference in distance between the set2 candidate and the point in set1, and is it equal to the minimum distance between that point in set1 and all the points in set2?
# Will return TRUE if the closest point is correctly idenfied.
dist_to_candidate = distm(set1[rand,], set2_closest_candidate, fun = distHaversine)/1609

min_dist_to_set2  = (distm(set1[rand,], set2, fun = distHaversine)/1609) %>% min

set2_id_min_dist  = set2$ID[which.min(distm(set1[rand,], set2, fun = distHaversine)/1609)]

# Tests
dist_to_candidate == min_dist_to_set2
set1[rand,]$ClosestID == set2_id_min_dist


# Is the distance obtained correctly? Should match `(distm(set1[rand,], set2, fun = distHaversine)/1609) %>% min`
set1@data$ClosestDist[rand] == (distm(set1[rand,], set2, fun = distHaversine)/1609) %>% min
```